# Success message fades out after first form submit but not after subsequent submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

The first time a submit form the success message displays and then fades correctly. If I submit form again then it doesn't work. I want it to repeat the display of message and subsequent fade out after each form submit.

I found this answer

[Trying to have a JQuery flash message after an ajax from submit in show again after more than one form submit (in rails)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34961956/trying-to-have-a-jquery-flash-message-after-an-ajax-from-submit-in-show-again-af)

but couldn't get to work, I'm very new to all this so be gentle ;-)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#editMember").submit(function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {

       url: "php/adminUpdateMember.php",
       method: "post",
       data: $("form").serialize(),
       dataType: "text",
       success: function(strMessage) {
       $("#message").text(strMessage);

                    }
                });
            });

     setTimeout(function() {
    $('#message').fadeOut('fast');
            }, 4000);
        });
```

Comment: After the first execution of `.fadeOut()` it cannot fade out again if it is no longer on display. If you add `$('#message').fadeIn('fast');` after `$("#message").text(strMessage);` should fix your problem.

Comment: Please read my first comment. I have edited the comment to explain how you can show the element again.

Comment: Yes i realised sorry!! Tried your fix but on second submit fade out doesnt occur

Comment: Move your `setTimeout()` into the `success: function()` Maybe under `$("#message").text(strMessage);` [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/jzNNGcU0)

Comment: Come to think of it, since you are using `jQuery` you can remove the `setTimeout()` and use `.delay()` and have the `#message` update/fadein & fadeout all in one line. `$('#message').text(strMessage).fadeIn('fast').delay(4000).fadeOut('fast');` Here is a [**PasteBin**](https://pastebin.com/tK57iqjq)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

            $("#editMember").submit(function(e) {

                e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax( {

                    url: "php/adminUpdateMember.php",
                    method: "post",
                    data: $("form").serialize(),
                    dataType: "text",
                    success: function(strMessage) {
                        $("#message").text(strMessage);
                        $('#message').fadeIn('fast');



                    }
                });
                setTimeout(function() {
            $('#message').fadeOut('fast');

            }, 4000);

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setTimeout() call is not inside your submit() block. It will trigger the fadeOut 4 seonds after page load, and not be called again.
You might also need to call $('#message').show(), to make the element visible after it's been faded out.

Comment: Excellent, this worked, about the only option I didn't try before I posted on here